# Banner image doesn't load with Hippo CMS

Tags: tomcat8, hippocms

I have been applying custom html/css layout to hippo. in `homepage-main.ftl` I have an image which is 1366x518 and ~400KB in size. Here's how it's implemented.
`<img src="<@hst.webfile path="/images/homebanner.jpg"/>"/>` However, when I run Hippo CMS it doesn't load (404 error in Chrome dev tool console) the banner image but it shows all the other images. I checked cms.war and i found this image inside `cms->WEB-INF->lib->[projectname]-bootstrap-content-[snapshot version].jar`. I put a small size image instead of homebanner.jpg and it worked. I am not sure whether this is an issue on Hippo CMS or Tomcat 8 configuration. any answer would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer:
Webfiles are limited to 256kb by default, it won't pick up anything bigger.
See also: http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/web-files/web-files-configuration.html if you want to change the max file size.

I would reccomend looking at making your banner configurable from within the CMS and using Imagesets for larger sizes.

Comment: Thanks, I uploaded the images into public place and accessed it via it's url. Anyway this is really helpful.

Comment: If you have some time, try and convert your banner to a catalog item: http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/hst-configuration-model/catalog-configuration.html it makes it a lot easier to change images on the fly.